# How to filter an array and add values to a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have the current state as:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "One", isChecked: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Two", isChecked: true },
    { id: 3, name: "Three", isChecked: false }
    ]);
```

I map through the state and display the data in a div and call a onClicked function to toggle the `isChecked` value on click:

```
    const clickData = index => {
      const newDatas = [...data];
      newDatas[index].isChecked = !newDatas[index].isChecked;
      setData(newDatas);

    const newSelected = [...selected];
    const temp = datas.filter(isChecked==true) // incomplete code, struggling here.
    const temp = datas.isChecked ? 
    };
```

I have another empty state called clicked:
`const[clicked, setClicked] = setState([])`. I want to add all the objected whose isChecked is true from the datas array to this array. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do that inside your clickData function. If the new isClicked is true then you push the data onto a clone of clicked and set the clone as the new clicked. If it isn't and is in clicked, you make a clone, remove it from that clone and set the clone as the new clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add checkBox & onChange event  instead of using div & onClick event for your understanding

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "One", isChecked: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Two", isChecked: true },
    { id: 3, name: "Three", isChecked: false }
  ]);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([]);

  const clickData = index => {
    let tempData = data.map(res => {
      if (res.id !== index) {
        return res;
      }
      res.isChecked = !res.isChecked;
      return res;
    });
    setClicked(tempData.filter(res => res.isChecked));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setClicked(data.filter(res => res.isChecked));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((res, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={res.isChecked}
            key={i}
            onChange={() => {
              clickData(res.id);
            }}
          />
          <label>{res.name}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
      {clicked.map(({ name }, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y4fdzm?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you're iterating through your data in a similar fashion:

```js
{data.map((obj, index) => <div key={index} onClick={handleClick}>{obj.name}</div>}
```

You can add a data attribute where you assign the checked value for that element, so something like this:

```js
{data.map((obj, index) => <div key={index} data-checked={obj.isChecked} data-index={index} onClick={handleClick}>{obj.name}</div>}
```

From this, you can now update your `isClicked` state when the `handleClick` function gets called, as such:

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()

   const checked = event.target.getAttribute("data-checked")
   const index = event.target.getAttribute("data-index")

   // everytime one of the elements get clicked, it gets added to isClicked array state if true
   If (checked) {
      let tempArr = [ ...isClicked ]
      tempArr[index] = checked
      setClicked(tempArr)
   }
}
```

That will let you add the items to your array one by one whenever they get clicked, but if you want all your truthy values to be added in a single click, then you simply need to write your `handleClick` as followed:

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()

   // filter data objects selecting only the ones with isChecked property on true
   setClicked(data.filter(obj => obj.isChecked))
}
```

My apologies in case the indentation is a bit off as I've been typing from the phone. Hope this helps!